# How to reference a function defined inside prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a functionality to a web page that uses a jquery library which doesn't seem to have any documentation. (unknown origin) my problem is mainly due to the lack of understanding on jquery plugin model and/or inner workings of javascript.

**1. the plugin is initiated as follows**

```
jQuery('div.carousel').scrollGallery({
                mask: 'div.mask',
                slider: 'div.slideset',
                slides: 'div.slide', ............ });
```

**2. the plugin is defined in jquery as follows**

```
;(function($){
        function ScrollGallery(options) {
                this.options = $.extend({
                        mask: 'div.mask', ...... }, options);
                this.init();
```

**3. in the `Object.prototype` declaration i see the following function `numSlide` defined.**

```
ScrollGallery.prototype = {
....................
numSlide: function(c) {
                        if(this.currentStep != c) {
                                this.currentStep = c;
                                this.switchSlide();
                        }
                },
.......... };
```

**Question.**

How do i reference `numSlide(int)` function externally?.

I tried the following methods and it did not work.

```
myx = jQuery('div.carousel').scrollGallery({ // var myx was added in the global scope
myx.numSlide(1); //error undefined is not a function
```

i tried adding `return this;` at the end of `myx = jQuery('div.carousel').scrollGallery({` but it still returns the jQuery object.

i also tried

```
jQuery.scrollGallery().numSlide(2); //error undefined is not a function
jQuery.scrollGallery.numSlide(2); //same error
```

Do i need to add **LIGHT BULB**

```
// jquery plugin
        $.fn.scrollGallery = function(opt){
                return this.each(function(){
                        $(this).data('ScrollGallery', new ScrollGallery($.extend(opt,{holder:this})));
                });
        };
}(jQuery));
```

**ANSWER** (I think)

it looks like the ScrollGalary object is stored in a data for the selector. So i believe i can do the following `jQuery('selector').data('ScrollGallery').numSlide(2);`

I decided to post this anyway in-case if anyone in the future had a similar gullible situation.

Comment: Please [post your answer as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), not in the question. It's correct btw, the way your plugin is written enforces this.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this will be to initiate **ScrollGallery** object first and then use it.

```
var test = new ScrollGallery();
test.numSlide();
```

if you want to extend jQuery and use the function you can assign it as follows

```
$.fn.scrollGallery = new ScrollGallery();
```

and use it

```
$("window").scrollGallery.numSlide();
```